# How to test mobile web apps using nightwatch?

Tags: automated-tests, appium, nightwatch.js

I already have some e2e test in nightwatch. I want to run the same scripts for my mobile web app(not native app). Is there any way to utilize the existing scripts to run on the mobile web app using nightwatch ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you can not do that as NightwatchJS does not support anything apart from Web based UI automation. However, you can definitely try [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/) which supports mobile automation for both Android and iOS. You can find the sample projects [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/boilerplate.html).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Raju for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

This is Vishal here and I have recently joined as a Product Manager for the same. It might be a little late to respond to this thread. But I am happy to inform you that Nightwatch does support Mobile Web via Appium. Here is the documentation link for the same.

https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/mobile-web-testing/with-appium.html